# how to delete element in the list in a for loop

Tags: python, list

how to delete element the list in a for loop?
the variable a should not be reassign .modify it but don't make new one.
the code below doesn't work properly

```
a = [1,2,2,3,2,1,4]
i = 0
for j in a:
    print(j)
    if(j<=2):
        print('deleting ',i)
        del a[i]
    else:
        i+=1     
print(a) #[3, 2, 1, 4]
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
a[:]=filter(lambda x:x<=2,a)
```

use filter...

or  list comprehension

```
a[:] = [itm for itm in a if itm > 2]
```

\edited to not destroy the original pointer... although im not sure why... seems like less than perfect design

Comment: This reassigns `a`, you need to assign the result to `a[:]` instead

Comment: why ? it removes the ref to the old a(thus scheduling old mem for GC) and now a is a with desired elements removed ... It doesnt sound like he wants the original array and it should eval right side entirely before assigning (at least im pretty sure)   ....

Comment: @gnibbler Yes, it reassigns it -- it *doesn't* modify the contents, but replaces what the variable points to.

Comment: "modify it but don't make a new one" sounds like the reference should be left alone and just the contents changed. Perhaps the reference is linked elsewhere in another data structure or a function is trying to modify a list as a sideeffect

Comment: ok fixed ... although I cant think of a good reason for this behavior

Answer (score 4):

You can iterate over a *copy* of the list

```
for j in a[:]:
```

Another way to solve you problem is

```
a[:] = [j for j in a if j>2]
```

Here `a[:]` indicates that the contents of `a` should be replaced by the list comprehension

Comment: +1 since you show him how to do it in a for loop like he asked in original question :)

Answer (score 2):

You shouldn't delete the elements of a list you're currently iterating over. It can mess up the index of the iteration - if the list arbitrarily changes while python iterates over it, how does it know which element should be the 'correct' one to iterate next?

Instead, use filter() or list comprehension, like Joran has suggested, or iterate over a copy of the list.

Answer (score 0):

While the suggestions in the other answers are likely to be best if filtering elements out of the list is the only thing you're doing in your loop, if you're doing a bunch of other stuff and only incidentally deleting some items at the end, iterating over the list's indexes may be a better approach than `filter` or a list comprehension:

```
for i in range(len(a)-1, -1, -1): # iterate in reverse order
    val = a[i]

    # do a bunch of stuff with val and/or i

    if (some_condition(val)):
        a.pop(i)
```

The iteration is in reverse so that we don't need to worry about our indexing getting messed up when we delete items.

Comment: Deleting items will still be slow since the higher elements all need to be shifted down one spot every time you delete one.

Comment: Yeah, that's why I suggested that this is only a good idea if the "other stuff" you're doing in the loop is more important (and more time consuming) than removing certain items from the list.